# Getting started with google app script - can not retrieve form submission parameters

Tags: google-apps-script

I am getting started with Google app script.  I have a function that is triggered on form submit.  Im am trying to access the properties inside e ([formResponse class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response)).  I don't succed and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my script :

```
function formSubmitReply(e) {
    Logger.log(Utilities.jsonStringify(e));
    Logger.log(Utilities.jsonStringify(e.getTimestamp() ));
    Logger.log("success");
}
```

When I submit a form, this is the log :

```
[13-10-03 09:36:54:026 EDT] {"response":"FormResponse"}
```

And this is the error from the code transcript :

```
[13-10-03 09:36:54:061 EDT] Échec de l'exécution du script : TypeError: Cannot find function getTimestamp in object [object Object]. (line 9, file "Code") [durée totale d'exécution : 0.034 secondes]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation: [Understanding Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events), you should try something like:

```js
...
Logger.log(Utilities.jsonStringify(e.response.getTimestamp()));
...
```